# How to add a timer on page load that stops when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, button, timer, mouseevent, milliseconds

I want to add a timer to the page where it starts on page load.

Where it goes up in milliseconds.

Then stops when the mouse is clicked on the button.

How would I create a code example of that?

That is all I am trying to do in the code.

Add a timer that starts on page load.

Goes up in milliseconds.

Then stops when the button is clicked.

**I want to be able to see** the numbers going up.

https://jsfiddle.net/xvkwmndq/

```js
// Counter
    var enterDate = new Date();
    function secondsSinceEnter()
    {
      return (new Date() - enterDate) / 1000;
    }

    // Usage example
    document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
      var sec = secondsSinceEnter();
      if (sec < 10)
          this.innerText = sec + " seconds";
      else
          this.innerText = 'You are here like for eternity';
    };
```

```css
.play {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: auto;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 90px;
      height: 90px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      cursor: pointer;
      border: 9px solid blue;
      background: transparent;
      filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px #000000b3);
    }
```

```html
<button class="play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself before asking this question?

Comment: Yes I have.....

Comment: The numbers are not appearing on the screen. https://jsfiddle.net/53d7wunz/ I want to be able to see the numbers going up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related to the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/53d7wunz/) in your comment:

Don't use `this` to access the button. Instead, just use `document.querySelector`:

```
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  var sec = secondsSinceEnter();
  if (sec < 10)
    document.querySelector('button').innerText = sec + " seconds";
  else
    document.querySelector('button').innerText = 'You are here like for eternity';
}
```

Then, you're just adding the time when the button is clicked. Additionally, you should call it every 0ms (every 'tick') using `setInterval`. So that you don't have to write the function twice, you could define it as a seperate function. Finally, remove the interval when the button is clicked.

Full script:

```
// Interval
var interval;

// Counter
var enterDate = new Date();
function secondsSinceEnter()
{
  return (new Date() - enterDate) / 1000;
}

// Event function
function evtFct()
{
  var sec = secondsSinceEnter().toFixed(3);
  if (sec < 10)
    document.querySelector('button').innerText = sec + " seconds";
  else
    document.querySelector('button').innerText = 'You are here like for eternity';
}

// Add interval to keep the current time uptodate
interval = setInterval(evtFct, 0); // Call evtFct every tick

// Usage example
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function()
{
  evtFct();
  clearInterval(interval); // Disable interval
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to see the numbers going up on the screen. Then for the numbers to stop when the button is clicked. How am I able to do that?

Comment: I copied and pasted that into the fiddle and it did not work: https://jsfiddle.net/jsp7agk0/1/ You may need to fix, or adjust the code you posted.

Comment: It's still not working: https://jsfiddle.net/87hfd1eu/

Comment: The numbers there going up seem to be all over the place. This one seems to be more accurate. https://www.estopwatch.net/

Comment: I've updated my answer, but additionally you should set the font-family of the timer to `monospace`

Comment: See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pwca5u2s/)